# TypeError: this.getAttribute is not a function - javascript

Tags: javascript

I cannot figure out why i cannot get the property of 'this' in the code below:

```
var Deferjs = {

init: function(){
    if(document.getElementById('js-currentPage')!=null){
        var file = this.getAttribute('data-page');
        Deferjs.LoadJs(file);
    }
},

LoadJs:function(file){
    alert("ok");
}
}

Deferjs.init();
```

However if i change
this.getAttribute('data-page'); to document.getElementById('js-currentPage').getAttribute it works

Please help me understand the above

thx

Comment: I think `this` does not contain what you think in the if statement, replacing it with `document.getElementById('js-currentPage')` should solve your issue

Comment: `this` is not referring to `document.getElementById('js-currentPage')`

Comment: what do you think  `this` points

Comment: i don't want to duplicate the same code again, that is why i tried with "this"

Comment: this should point to document.getElement.ById("js-currentPage") ?

Answer (score 2):

if you want to reuse `document.getElementById('js-currentPage')` save it in a variable. you can not refer it with `this` in your case `this` points to the container object (`DeferJs`)

```
init: function(){
    var elem=document.getElementById('js-currentPage');
    if(elem!=null){
        var file = elem.getAttribute('data-page');
        Deferjs.LoadJs(file);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(document.getElementById('js-currentPage')!=null){
        var file = this.getAttribute('data-page');
```

Here `this` will refer to `Deferjs`. Instead you must store the reference to the DOM to a variable if you want to access it else where.

```
   var ele = document.getElementById('js-currentPage');
   if(ele!=null){
            var file = ele.getAttribute('data-page');
```

Answer (score 0):

your init function resides in Deferjs, thus, when you use "this", it's referring to Deferjs. Deferjs does not have a function named getAttribute. you need to use

```
document.getElementById('js-currentPage').getAttribute(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

***DOM*** actually provides a set of ***API*** to access HTML elements, and this pointer points to the scope of the object, which can only access the attributes ***class, ID, style***, etc.

In the scope of the object, that is, you can access through the object attributes (***this.data-message***). However, there is ***no getAttribute() method*** in the scope of the object, so you cannot use ***this.getAttribute().***